# Azure Container Registry Permissions Using Terraform

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, terraform

Setting up a `azurerm_container_registry` with terraform, I was wondering how I can change the permissions for certain users (e.g. `ReadOnly`), or perhaps to create a `access_key` which can be used from my CI-Pipeline, but does not require a user at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Terraform configuration creates an ACR registry, and Azure Service Principal, 
and grants the SP `contributor` access to the ACR registry. This can be updated to `reader`.

More information can be found on ACR auth with service principals [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal/?WT.mc_id=stackoverflow-stackoverflow-nepeters).

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "acr-rg" {
  name     = "acr-rg-007"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                = "acr00722"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.acr-rg.name}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.acr-rg.location}"
  sku                 = "standard"
}

resource "azurerm_azuread_application" "acr-app" {
  name = "acr-app"
}

resource "azurerm_azuread_service_principal" "acr-sp" {
  application_id = "${azurerm_azuread_application.acr-app.application_id}"
}

resource "azurerm_azuread_service_principal_password" "acr-sp-pass" {
  service_principal_id = "${azurerm_azuread_service_principal.acr-sp.id}"
  value                = "Password12"
  end_date             = "2020-01-01T01:02:03Z"
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "acr-assignment" {
  scope                = "${azurerm_container_registry.acr.id}"
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = "${azurerm_azuread_service_principal_password.acr-sp-pass.service_principal_id}"
}

output "docker" {
  value = "docker login ${azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server} -u ${azurerm_azuread_service_principal.acr-sp.application_id} -p ${azurerm_azuread_service_principal_password.acr-sp-pass.value}"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snipped, this works pretty well as `contributor`. But when I do give the SP access as `reader`, I am not able to see the docker registry, e.g. logging in with `az login --service-principal -u <application_id> -p Password12 --tenant <tenant_id>` and doing a `az acr repository list --name acr` does not show me the images.